# why is node.js giving the following error?

Tags: mysql, node.js

I followed the https://www.w3schools.com/nodejs/nodejs_mysql.asp to install node.js, then created the code to connect to mysql db. once i ran the node.js command it gave me errors. I am new to using this software.

```
error:  
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:896
            
throw err;
  ^
Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\admin\db_connection.js'

[90m    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:893:15)[39m

[90m    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:743:27)[39m

[90m    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:72:12)[39m

[90m    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47[39m {

  code: [32m'MODULE_NOT_FOUND'[39m,

  requireStack: []
}
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: The error is quite explicit: `Cannot find module 'C:\Users\admin\db_connection.js`. Do you have a file at this location?

Comment: The instructions tell you, to save your code to a file named `demo_db_connection.js` and then run the file with `node demo_db_connection.js`. I bet you have called `node db_connection.js` (note the missing `demo_` in the filename)

Comment: i added the file to the directory within a txt file named db_connection.js , so i am unsure why it does not find the file.

Comment: BTW: saving codefiles and installing local npm modules directly into the users home directory, without any subdirectories is quite a messy thing to do, regardless what any tutorial says ...

Comment: how did you create the file? Right click -> Next Text document in the explorer? Maybe windows explorer is configured to hide known extensions (default) and your file is called `db_connection.js.txt`  Open a CMD in that directory and execute `dir *db_connection*` and check if it lists a file `db_connection.js

Comment: Issue solved, the issue i was having is that windows saved the file as TXT and not .js, once i changed the extension it worked as it should have. Thank you for all your help and comments.